# Klein-Gordon Charge Acting Like Angular Momentum

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, angular-momentum, klein-gordon-equation

This post is referring to the solution of exercise 2.2(d) of Peskin and Schroeder's *An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory*. Once again, I am using the manual provided by Dr. Zhong-Zhi Xianyu. Equation (2.27) in the manual provides the value of $[Q^a, Q^b]$ in $SU(N)$. I am currently working in $SU(2)$ whose generators are the pauli sigma matrices. I was able to get the third to last line of Equation (2.27) which I present below (the differences between this and the one presented in the manual are that the matrices presented here are the Pauli matrices and I dropped the Dirac delta):

$$\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\bigg[\alpha_{ip}^\dagger\sigma_{ij}^a \sigma_{jl}^b \alpha_{lp} - \alpha_{kp}^\dagger \sigma_{kl}^b \sigma_{lj}^a \alpha_{jp} + \beta_{ip}^\dagger\sigma_{ij}^a \sigma_{jl}^b \beta_{lp} - \beta_{kp}^\dagger \sigma_{kl}^b \sigma_{lj}^a \beta_{jp}\bigg]$$

The second to last line of equation (2.27) says that this is equal to

$$i\epsilon^{abc}\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \bigg[\alpha_{ip}^\dagger \sigma^c_{il} \alpha_{lp} - \beta_{kp}^\dagger \sigma_{kj}^c \beta_{jp} \bigg]$$

To try to prove this, I used the identity $\sigma^a \sigma^b = \delta_{ab}1 + i\epsilon_{abc}\sigma^c$. From this I see $\sigma_i^a \cdot \sigma_l^b = \delta_{ab}\delta_{il}1 + i\epsilon_{abc}\sigma^c_{il}$ and $\sigma_k^a \cdot \sigma_j^b = \delta_{kj}\delta_{ab}1 + i\epsilon_{abc}\sigma^c_{kj}$.

Thus the first integrand I presented becomes $$(\alpha_{ip}^\dagger \alpha_{lp})(\delta_{ab}\delta_{il}1 + i\epsilon_{abc}\sigma^c_{il}) - (\alpha_{kp}^\dagger \alpha_{jp})(\delta_{kj}\delta_{ab}1 + i\epsilon_{bac}\sigma^c_{kj}) + (\beta_{ip}^\dagger \beta_{lp})(\delta_{il}\delta_{ab}1 + i\epsilon_{abc}\sigma^c_{lp}) - (\beta_{kp}^\dagger \beta_{jp})(\delta_{ab}\delta_{kj}1 + i\epsilon_{bac}\sigma^c_{kj})$$

Now if $a = b$, I see that the $\epsilon_{abc}$'s becomes $0$, and so I obtain $$\alpha_{ip}^\dagger \alpha_{lp}\delta_{il} - \alpha_{kp}^\dagger \alpha_{jp}\delta_{kj} + \beta_{ip}^\dagger \beta_{lp}\delta_{il} - \beta_{kp}^\dagger \beta_{jp}\delta_{kj}.$$ Now the j's,k's, i's, and l's are dummy indicies, since the are used for summation and so we see that the first pair cancel and the second pair cancel. Thus the integrand is 0 (**Is this logic correct?**)

Now suppose $a \neq b$. Then the delta's are 0 and I obtain:

$$(\alpha_{ip}^\dagger \alpha_{lp})( i\epsilon_{abc}\sigma^c_{il}) - (\alpha_{kp}^\dagger \alpha_{jp})(i\epsilon_{bac}\sigma^c_{kj}) + (\beta_{ip}^\dagger \beta_{lp})( i\epsilon_{abc}\sigma^c_{lp}) - (\beta_{kp}^\dagger \beta_{jp})(i\epsilon_{bac}\sigma^c_{kj})$$

Now, the second and third terms do not cancel, and I am unable to recover the desired result. **Can anyone show me what I did wrong? I believe I made all the indices adjustments.**

Comment: Hint: the indices of $\delta_{ab}1 + i\epsilon_{abc}\sigma^c_{kj}$ don't make sense.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Should the indices of the delta and levi-cevita symbol be i's,j's,k's? I'm not sure why these would be the indices, especially since in the solutions manual for SU(N), the author uses the tensor $f^{abc}$. Can you please explain more?

Comment: The delta and the levi-civita symbol are both fine. But why would you multiply the first by something indexless and the second by something that has $kj$ indices? That is more than likely what's throwing you off.

Comment: @ConnorBehan I fixed the indicies you mentioned. However, I still do not understand why the operator products do not cancel when $a = b$ and why the middle terms cancel when $a \neq b$?

Comment: Not everything has been fixed. You are still adding something with $kj$ indices to something which doesn't have $kj$ indices. This is like adding a length to an energy.

Comment: @ConnorBehan I made the change, but I still have the same question.

Comment: You haven't made the important change. $\delta_{ab}1$ has different indices from $i\epsilon_{abc}\sigma^c_{il}$ and yet you are adding the two. This is your confusion.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: If your problem is solved, consider writing an answer to your own question to help future readers.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Sorry to bother you again, but I believe I made the indices changes (although I am not sure how I should incorporate c into the delta's). I still do not get the desired result. Can you explain what is wrong with my logic?

Comment: Your first bold statement is correct. For your second bold statement, the goal is not to cancel anything but to show that the two $\alpha$ terms are the same and the two $\beta$ terms are the same. This is affected by a typo where two of your $\epsilon_{abc}$'s should really be $\epsilon_{bac}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is answer to my question, which I got with the help of @Connor Behan. The $a = b$ case is shown in the question post. For the $a\neq b$ case we have

$(\alpha_{ip}^\dagger \alpha_{lp})( i\epsilon_{abc}\sigma^c_{il}) - (\alpha_{kp}^\dagger \alpha_{jp})(i\epsilon_{bac}\sigma^c_{kj}) + (\beta_{ip}^\dagger \beta_{lp})( i\epsilon_{abc}\sigma^c_{lp}) - (\beta_{kp}^\dagger \beta_{jp})(i\epsilon_{bac}\sigma^c_{kj}) \\= (\alpha_{ip}^\dagger \alpha_{lp})( i\epsilon_{abc}\sigma^c_{il}) + (\alpha_{kp}^\dagger \alpha_{jp})(i\epsilon_{abc}\sigma^c_{kj}) + (\beta_{ip}^\dagger \beta_{lp})( i\epsilon_{abc}\sigma^c_{lp}) + (\beta_{kp}^\dagger \beta_{jp})(i\epsilon_{abc}\sigma^c_{kj}) $

Noting that $i's,l's, j's,k's$ are dummy indices, we can combine the first two terms and the last two terms.